# Anonymous function defined by a loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, anonymous-function

I use anonymous functions in my code. For example:

```
G = @(x) [norm(A*x-b);A'*(A*x-b)];
```

norm(Ax-b) is the objective function and A'*(Ax-b) the gradient.
Then,

```
Algo( G,varagin );
```

etc

What I would like to do is to define f with a loop:

```
n = 9;
k = 2;
t = 1 - x.^k;
f = 0;
for i=1:n
    f = f + x(i,1)*prod(t(1:i-1));
end
grad_f = zeros(n,1);
for i0=1:n
    s = t;
    s(i0) = [];
    for i=i0+1:n
        grad_f(i0) = grad_f(i0) + x(i)*prod(s(1:i0-1));
    end
    grad_f(i0) = -k*x(i0)^(k-1)*grad_f(i0);
    grad_f(i0) = grad_f(i0) + prod(t(1:i0-1));
end
```

Then I would like to do something like:

```
" G = @(x) [f,grad_f] "
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Anonymous functions are already "closures".  That means you can just define the anonymous function the way you normally do, referring to `grad_f` and `f` inside the expression, and the function object will store the values they had at time of definition.  If that's not your question, be a little more clear on what you want to happen and what isn't working.

Comment: G = @(x) [f,grad_f];
and then the loop doesn't work, because x has no meaning in the loop.

Could you please give an example of what your explaining?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're asking.  I can't tell whether you're trying to define a loop inside the function, or define the function inside the loop.  I think the problem in your question is from here on: "Then I would like to do something like:".  Replace that language with a clearer description of your intent.

Comment: Hmm... Why use an anonymous function at all?  Just make this code a regular MATLAB function in an m-file.

Comment: Because this function is an argument of Algo(G,varargin)

Comment: It doesn't have to be an anonymous function to be passed this way.  Just put it in an M-file like a normal function, with the correct returns, and pass it to your algorithm using a function handle.  See `help function_handle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:
create F(x) and GRAD_F(x) as functions in matlab computing f and grad_f respectively.
Then:

```
G = @(x) [F(x);GRAD_F(x)];
Algo(G,varargin);
```